# How to start selenium or puppeteer in existing REAL browser

Tags: selenium, webdriver, puppeteer

I don't want to start a plain new browser which is used for testing purposes. I need to start a new tab in my real chrome browser with all the bookmarks and extension available. Please provide a short code snippet. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a browser was not opened by Webdriver, [it is not possible](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18)

However using `puppeteer` you can launch your locally installed Chrome with bookmarks and profile:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
    args: ['--user-data-dir=C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/']
  }); 
  const page = await browser.newPage();
})();
```

The location of Chrome executable and user data directory can be found here: `chrome://version/` (ends with "User Data").

---

Using extensions are bit tricker:

> [By default, Puppeteer disables extensions when launching Chrome](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/tree/master/examples#load-a-chrome-extension). You can load a specific extension using:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  args: [
    '--disable-extensions-except=/path/to/extension/',
    '--load-extension=/path/to/extension/',
  ]
});
```

Or you can override defaults:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
    ignoreDefaultArgs : true,
    args:
    [
      '--user-data-dir=C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/',
      '--disable-background-networking',
      '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
      '--disable-client-side-phishing-detection',
      '--disable-default-apps',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      // '--disable-extensions',
      '--disable-hang-monitor',
      '--disable-popup-blocking',
      '--disable-prompt-on-repost',
      '--disable-sync',
      '--disable-translate',
      '--metrics-recording-only',
      '--no-first-run',
      '--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update',
    ]
  }); 
  const page = await browser.newPage();
})();
```